# Is 'the' a must here: within [the] production of electrical power for new buildings

Tags: definite-article

1. Solar energy is quickly becoming dominant within production of electrical power for new buildings in many countries
2. Solar energy is quickly becoming dominant within the production of electrical power for new buildings in many countries

Is 'the' an imperative here?

Comment: I'd put it because I'm talking about *production of electrical power* and nothing else. So, to me, it's specific require the definite article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences sounds wrong to me, because ***within*** and ***production*** seem strange in this sense.

[Here is the source](http://www.trelleborg.com/en/sealing-profiles/cases/sealing--the--solar--look) of the statement, which is a quote from Erik Martinson, of Svea Solar, [a Swedish company](https://sveasolar.se/en/vara-kontor/).  It [appears](https://se.linkedin.com/in/erik-martinson-114a3442) that English is not Mr. Martinson's first language.

If the word ***within*** was replaced with ***in***, then option #2 sounds a better than option #1:

> Solar energy is quickly becoming dominant in the production of electrical power for new buildings in many countries.

I would instead say something like:

> Solar energy is quickly gaining dominance as the primary power source for new buildings in many countries.

Comment: I believed 'within' is identical to 'in the field of', am I right?

Comment: I think you can get your point across with either, but technically the answer is no. See definition 6 here https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in as opposed to the definition of *within*, which is more of a "relative or physical location": https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/within